# application close automaticallty in android

Tags: android

I am new in android and running 6 async task concurrently. So for this I am using this

```
        int corePoolSize = 60;
        int maximumPoolSize = 80;
        int keepAliveTime = 10;
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maximumPoolSize);
        Executor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
        new FetchShoppingItems(GlobalVars.fetchshoppingURl, sipId).executeOnExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
```

This but my application close automatically without any crash message dialog. Please help me to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the memory issue. I fixed the issue just do increase the heap size to large.